# Errors while using replacement rules

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, rule

I am trying to evaluate the sum below by using replacement rule but it doesn't work. I got some errors saying "*...is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing*".

Could anyone explain why the error happened and how to fix it?

```
sol = Solve[{a + b + c == 3, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 29, a*b*c == 11}, {a, b, c}]; 
sum = a^5 /. sol[[1,1]] + b^5 /. sol[[1,2]] + c^5 /. sol[[1,3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***why the error happened***

`Plus` has higher precedence than `ReplaceAll`(see: [Operator Input Forms >> Operator Precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)), so addition is performed before replacement.

```
{#, Precedence @ #} & /@ {Plus, Rule, ReplaceAll}
```

> {{Plus, 310.}, {Rule, 120.}, {ReplaceAll, 110.}}

A simpler example that generates the same error is

```
a^5 /. sol[[1]] + 5
```

[image]

***how to fix it***

You can parenthesize the terms to make sure that `ReplaceAll` is performed before `Plus`:

```
sum = (a^5 /. sol[[1, 1]]) + (b^5 /. sol[[1, 2]]) + (c^5 /. sol[[1, 3]]);
N[sum]
```

> `4138. + 9.99201*10^-16 I`

Alternatively, you can use the following which avoids precedence issues:

```
sum2 = Total[{a, b, c}^5] /. sol[[1]];
N[sum2]
```

> `4138. + 9.99201*10^-16 I`

Comment: Thanks. Why when I try `a/.a->2 +5` there is no problem at all?

Comment: @anhnha, `a /. a->2 +5` the same as `a/. a-> (2 +5)` and gives, as expected 7.  The case in your question is more like `rule = a -> 2;
a /. rule + 5` (or, `a /. (a->2) +5`), and this form gives an error.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.